# Wordpress: Check if logged in users have post edit capabilities

Tags: wordpress

How to check in WordPress if a logged in user has specific capabilities (for example editing the post-type "product")? How to display the "Edit page" link to users which have the required capability?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php current_user_can( $capability , $object_id ); ?>
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_user_can

List of rights

https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities

Should always check the wordpress doc first